# Why does my domain not linking with godaddy hosting after I transferred the domain name from godaddy to big rock?

Tags: dns, hosting, web-hosting, transfer

I recently transferred the domain(v3foods.in)  from godaddy to big rock because there was an issue for violating the  rules which I didn't do wantedly. So I paid the fine  and transferred the domain.  Now when I try to link with the  same old hosting it is not linking up.  It is showing like A record not found which I entered and maintained for more than 48hrs. I feel like I  made a mistake somewhere so  can someone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can query for the NS like this :

```
nslookup -q=ns v3foods.in
```

reply is :

```
Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
v3foods.in      nameserver = dns3.bigrock.in.
v3foods.in      nameserver = dns1.bigrock.in.
v3foods.in      nameserver = dns4.bigrock.in.
v3foods.in      nameserver = dns2.bigrock.in.
```

Your Ping Data is now pointing to this Host

```
ping v3foods.in 
PING v3foods.in (23.229.248.68) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ip-23-229-248-68.ip.secureserver.net (23.229.248.68): icmp_req=1 ttl=56 time=68.8  ms
```

This is also the A record

Your Dig is now set for a very long time(in my opinion if you dont pay for DNS query set this to 5 min..)

```
 dig v3foods.in

 ; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> v3foods.in
 ;; global options: +cmd
 ;; Got answer:
 ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 36816
 ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

 ;; QUESTION SECTION:
 ;v3foods.in.                    IN      A
 ;; ANSWER SECTION:
 v3foods.in.             21595   IN      A       23.229.248.68
 ;; Query time: 17 msec
 ;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
 ;; WHEN: Mon Dec 22 17:50:13 2014
 ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 44
```

And this is the result from the NameServer at bigrock.in

```
 > v3foods.in
 Server:         dns3.bigrock.in
 Address:        67.15.253.219#53
 Name:   v3foods.in
 Address: 23.229.248.68
 >
```

If you can login into your hosting server run : ifconfig

this will show you the hosting External IP the format you will get will be eth0 - > inet addr: SERVER EXTERNAL IP

It seem like a straight A record Issue point to the right IP .. hope this help